# Laravel 5.3 bootstrap installed with bower not seen in view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, gulp

On my Laravel 5.3 app I followed [these](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/convert-laravel-5-frontend-scaffold-to-bower) steps (1, 2, 3, 5 and 6)
So I now have a public/js/vendor.js folder.
My view uses `<script src="{{ asset('/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>`
I skipped step 4 in the tutorial since Laravel 5.3 doesn't have a `less` folder in resources.

> Now, we need to update our scripts to pull in the new dependencies. In resources/less/app.less, change this:

Do I need to make changes to `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` instead? And what are those changes?

Or what is the best way to get bootstrap installed for Laravel 5.3 using bower and gulp?

My gulp.js:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
var gulp = require('gulp');


elixir(function(mix){
mix.scripts([
'../bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'../bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
], 
'public/js/vendor.js');
});
```

For step 4 I created a less folder in resources/assets. And created app.less. In it I've put `@import "../bower/bootstrap/less/bootstrap";`
gulp file: (has an error in now)

```
elixir(function(mix){
mix.scripts([
'../bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
'../bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
], 
'public/js/vendor.js');

mix.less(app.less);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why did you skipped step 4? You could add for example

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
```

to: `resources/assets/less/app.scss`

Then in your `gulp` file:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.less('app.scss');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Laravel 5.3 does not have `resources/assets/less/app.scss`

Comment: updated my question. My gulp file gets an error now that app is not defined.

Comment: try to rename app.less to app.scss

Comment: I forgot single quote marks in gulp file. Fixed now and my bootstrap is working. I have `<script src="{{ asset('/js/vendor.js') }}"></script>` and `<link rel=stylesheet href="{{ asset('/css/app.css') }}">` Thanks so much!